# Simplifying an expression using an additional relationship

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I have the expression

```
ss = 
  As μ 
    (2 I k η1 Sinh[y η1] - 
      (I k (2 k^2 - k2^2) Cosh[H η1] Sinh[y η2])/(η2 Cosh[H η2]) + 
      (I k2^2 (2 k^2 - k2^2) Cosh[H η1] Sinh[y η2])/(2 k η2 Cosh[H η2]));
```

I want to simplify it using the relation

```
-4 k^2 η1 η2 Cosh[H η2] Sinh[H η1] + (-2 k^2 + k2^2)^2 Cosh[H η1] Sinh[H η2] == 0
```

The answer is:

[image: the answer]

However, I couldn't do get that using Mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include your condition in `Solve` to eliminate `k2` in the equation `ss`:

```
Solve[{ss == As \[Mu]
(2 I k \[Eta]1 Sinh[
    y \[Eta]1] - (I k (2 k^2 - k2^2) Cosh[H \[Eta]1] Sinh[
      y \[Eta]2])/(\[Eta]2 Cosh[
      H \[Eta]2]) + (I k2^2 (2 k^2 - k2^2) Cosh[H \[Eta]1] Sinh[
      y \[Eta]2])/(2 k \[Eta]2 Cosh[
      H \[Eta]2])), -4 k^2 \[Eta]1 \[Eta]2 Cosh[H \[Eta]2] Sinh[
  H \[Eta]1] + (-2 k^2 + k2^2)^2 Cosh[H \[Eta]1] Sinh[
  H \[Eta]2] == 0}, ss, k2, Complexes]

(* {{ss -> 2 I As k \[Eta]1 \[Mu] Csch[H \[Eta]2] (Sinh[y \[Eta]1] Sinh[H \[Eta]2] - 
  Sinh[H \[Eta]1] Sinh[y \[Eta]2])}} *)
```

which is what you are looking for.

Comment: Putting `List` brackets around `k2` will clarify that it is a variable to be eliminated rather than a domain specification and eliminate the need to explicitly state the domain as `Complexes` to avoid the warning message. `Solve[eqns, ss, {k2}]`

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your answer(!) right you can solve your problem as follows:

```
ergk2=Solve[-4 k^2 η1 η2 Cosh[H η2] Sinh[H η1] + (-2 k^2 + k2^2)^2 Cosh[H η1] Sinh[H η2] == 0,k2]

Simplify[ss /. ergk2]
```

gives four solutions similar to the answer you expect!